# Need the value from one module into the component when that module is invoked

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a reactive forms module which comprises of 3 components.
Component 1 - Header component which is the part of the this component only.
Component 2 - This component is basically dynamic but another reactive forms module with 4 child components ( Child 1, Child 2, Child 3, Child 4 ) and I want to grab all these formgroup values into the Component 1 but didn't find any luck.
Component 3 - which the Footer component, consisting of Submit and Cancel button and grabbing all the values from Component 1 and Component 2, and passing as an input to the Component 3.

Component 2 is dynamically loaded based on the some parameters.

I want to achieve this functionality. How can we do this.

The approaches which I had tried using @Output, Subject and ViewChild didn't work.

IF the above approach can be tweaked or making this solution feasible.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: You can use [custom injection tokens & values](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#value-providers), or a [`forRoot` configuration](https://www.freelancermap.com/freelancer-tips/12255-forroot-forchild-angular)